# Is it preferred to have a `verify` call for each `when` call in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

When writing test cases the usual pattern is `setup` > `execute` > `verify`. This results in unit tests that look like this:

```
@Test
void testSomething() {
    // Setup
    when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn("someValue");
    
    // Execute (the doSomething implementation would invoke someMock.someMethod)
    testee.doSomething();
        
    // Verify
    verify(someMock, times(1)).someMethod();
}
```

My question is, is it necessary to include the `verify` call considering the when `call` will raise a `UnnecessaryStubbingException` exception?

This question only applies in cases where `times` is `1` since the absence of `UnnecessaryStubbingException` only implies that `someMethod` has been called once and with the correct arguments and there may be cases where you want to verify that `someMethod` has been called `never`. Without the verify the test would look like this and achieve the same checks:

```
@Test
void testSomething() {
    // Setup
    when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn("someValue");
    
    // Execute (the doSomething implementation would invoke someMock.someMethod)
    testee.doSomething();
}
```

Edit: A friend pointed out that `verifyNoMoreInteractions` relies on you having `verify` calls so I guess this is important to consider.

Edit 2: I've changed "necessary" to "preferred" in the title since I'm more interested in the pros/cons of each approach versus what is technically required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You almost answered your own question. Does throwing an **exception** confirm the correct execution? The **exception** itself is an indicator of incorrect behavior. Thus you can confirm that the method was called only once, or zero times, and not more than that, etc.

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi So to confirm, you think that the `verify` is NOT necessary since the absence of the exception implies the correct number of calls were made?

Comment: "A friend pointed out that verifyNoMoreInteractions relies on you having verify calls" no it doesn't. `verifyNoMoreInteractions` can be used by itself to verify that there were no interactions with the mock at all. For example, if you want to ensure that you don't send a mail in a given circumstance, you can verify that you didn't call `mailer.sendMail(someArgs)`; but that's brittle, because you might have called some other overload of `mailer.sendMail`, or some other method. Verifying that there was no interaction at all with the `mailer` is more robust.

Comment: My point was that using an **Exception** to indicate whether the test case was successful or not is a **bad** design. You **should** use `assert` and `verify` to make sure that your code was executed just as you expect it to be.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think you might be referring to `verifyNoInteractions`? As far as I am aware `verifyNoMoreInteractions` is used when you have other `verify` calls and then want to make sure that the given mock is not called again.

Comment: @beardo you can use either. There is no requirement for you to use verify before VNMI.

Comment: @AndyTurner TIL. I think this could still lead to issues in the case where you do have some `verify` calls (i.e. on methods where `times` > 1), omit the `verify` calls to methods where `times` is `1` and then use `VNMI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not *necessary*, as you mentioned - technically test validates this behavior. So the choice should go from preferences and expertise of your team. I personally think **having explicit verification step** makes your test more readable and maintainable. Few reasons:

- You can have more `when` invocations, not relevant to verification logic, this will "hide" the test intention, e.g.

```
@Test
void testSomething() {
    // Setup
    when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn("someValue");
    when(someMock2.someMethod2()).thenReturn("someValue2");
    when(someMock3.someMethod3()).thenReturn("someValue3");
    
    // Execute (the doSomething implementation 
    // would invoke someMock.someMethod)
    testee.doSomething();

    // code reviewer - "hm? what do we really test here?"
}
```

- From API perspective throwing of exception in `UnnecessaryStubbingException` in `when` is not obvious - this can bring a confusion for occasional code reader who missed that fact. Having `verify` makes the intention of test clear for almost any developer, even coming from other tech stack
- Some developers can come from earlier Mockito versions where throwing of `UnnecessaryStubbingException` was not the case
- `UnnecessaryStubbingException` is only raised when Mockito is in strict mode. If this setting is changed to lenient down the line you'd no longer be able to rely on this exception being raised.
- You can create scenarios where not including `verify` calls means subsequent `verifyNoMoreInteractions` calls will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I was actually mid editing the title while you commented to reflect necessary vs preferential - good point. I think all of the other points are also valid and well made.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already aware that your piece of code will throw an exception, its better to have a test case covering it like below

@Test(expected = UnnecessaryStubbingException.class)

A test case(the one you have shown skipping verify) without any assertion or verify statement has no meaning in it. It's a good approach to have verify check for cases when methods have void return type.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not necessary to add **Verify** for each when call in Mockito. Every testcase should be deterministic in nature.

To answer your question the preferred way is to use in this particular case is to `verifyNoMoreInteractions` or `verify(somemock, never()).someMethod()`

It is not necessary that you always need verify. You can use **assertions** as well. But, **A testcase must have either of them**.

For Eg. If you are sure that some method is going to throw an Exception.

```java
@Test(expected = HeyIAmException.class)
void testSomething() {
     classUnderTest.someMethodWhichThrowsException();
}
```

or In Junit 5.

```
@Test
void testSomething() {
     when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn("someValue");
     HeyIAmException exception = assertThrows(HeyIAmException.class, () ->
                    classUnderTest.someMethodWhichThrowsException()
     );
    
     assertEquals(exception.getCode(),rightCode);
}
```

In your approach addition to Udalmik's answer I have following more lines to add.

- We will never know which stub method have caused exception, as any of the `someMethod` could throw the exception.
- The intention of the test is not very clear.